# xcode source control trap: unable to index file

Tags: xcode, git, git-commit, xcdatamodel

I checked out a new branch of a good production build, and added a new core data model.  It failed to build (separate issue) and in the process of troubleshooting, I removed the new model from the project.  Now, Xcode fails to commit changes, with errors:

> error: unable to index file '[project directory]/Core
>   data/XXXCloudKitModel.xcdatamodeld' fatal: updating files failed

and

> the path 'XXXCloudKitModel.xcdatamodeld' exists but is not a tree (-3)

No effect from re-adding the model to the same path.  I'd be willing to revert back to a prior commit, but when I try to check one out, I get:

> There was an error stashing a working copy. The pull operation cannot
>   proceed until this error is fixed.

Discarding the changes that appear in project.xcworkspace file is no help.  With that, I am stuck here.  Any ideas?   I'll admit to very rudimentary knowledge of source control...